# Change Language from Chinese to English in Cent OS 6.4?

Tags: centos

How do you change the language completely into English from Chinese in Cent OS 6.4?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on this question, please?  Is even the command line (tty console) in Chinese or is it “just” your graphical user interface?  If it is just the GUI, please let us know which desktop environment you are using.

Comment: I'm very new to this Linux system, everything is in Chinese, my friend change it for me, but it only changed some folder names. Now even if I open the terminal all the (F), (E), (V), (S), (T), and (H) titles are in Chinese. I want to change it completely into English.